# How to send parameters via the URL to PHP from Flex HttpService

Tags: php, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, httpservice

Forgive me if this has already been answered/ is extremely basic/ the question is worded incorrectly, I am very new to this and struggling.

Basically I have back end PHP which generates XML, the flash builder then inherits the data. Where I'm stuck is understanding how the flash builder can send a parameter to the PHP through an HttpService e.g

This is what it currently interprets:

```
http://..../file.php?action=getitems
```

What I would like the flash builder to send is

```
&class=fruit (<- the class would be dependant on what is selected from the drop down in the application)
```

to overall create this string

```
http://..../file.php?action=getitems&class=fruit
```

Thank you and apologies if this is nonsense. I'm using Flash Builder 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually rather simple in Flex...

```
var service : HTTPService = new HTTPService();
service.url = "http://localhost/getData.php";
service.method = "POST";


var parameters:Object = new Object();
parameters["action"] = "getitems";
parameters["class"] = "fruit";

service.send(parameters);
```

... done!

Answer (score 1):

Overall I would use the push method instead of passing a variable, lessens the chance of getting hacked from the middle.

My AS3 Code for the http call:

```
    public function someRequest() : void
    {
        var service : HTTPService = new HTTPService();
        service.url = "http://localhost/getData.php";
        service.useProxy = false;
        service.method = "POST";
        service.contentType = "application/xml";    // Pass XML data.
        service.request = "<ID>somevalue</ID>";     // The XML data.
        service.resultFormat = "xml";               // Recieve XML data.
        service.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, createFields);
        service.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, handleFault);
        service.send();
    }

    private function createFields(event : ResultEvent) : void
    {
        var result : String = event.result.toString();
        returnData = XML(result);
    }

    private function handleFault(event : FaultEvent) : void
    {
        var faultstring : String = event.fault.faultString;
        Alert.show(faultstring);
    }
```

As you see toward the middle, there is an XML space for entering a variable.  I use this approach to pass data back and forth from the PHP to the AS3.

The PHP is:

```
<?php

define("DATABASE_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DATABASE_USERNAME", "root");
define("DATABASE_PASSWORD", "**");
define("DATABASE_NAME", "dbName");

//connect to the database.
$mysql = mysql_connect(DATABASE_SERVER, DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD);

mysql_select_db(DATABASE_NAME);

$Query  = "SELECT * from data WHERE employeeID = '" . ($_POST['ID']) . "'";
$Result = mysql_query($Query);

$Return = "<data>";

while ($User = mysql_fetch_object($Result))
{
    $Return .= "<user><userid>" . $User->userid . "</userid><username>" . $User->username . "</username><emailaddress>" . $User->emailaddress . "</emailaddress></user>";
}
$Return .= "</data>";
mysql_free_result($Result);
print ($Return)
?>
```

Hope that helps you on your way.

Comment: Just a comment, either I'm blind, of I can't find where/how you're referring to the passed data in your PHP example.

Comment: I added comments to the three lines of code that are used to pass the XML data to and from the AS3.  They are the .contentType, .request and .resultFormat lines.  I find it easy to work in XML as mySQL works cleanly with it, but you could change the descriptors in those lines to work with the data format of your choice.

Comment: Yes, but your **php** sample doesn't show how to access the passed data. If you're going to provide sample code, it should probably explain the answer?

Comment: Sorry about that, I had 2 windows open and copied the PHP from the wrong one.  I have corrected it above.  You use the passed variables via the $_POST[xml_var], that way they are not needed in your URL.

Answer (score 1):

I generally handle this through [POST] instead of [GET]

In your actionscript function:

```
private function sendRequest():void {
var obj:Object = new Object();
obj.action="getitems";
obj.class="fruit";

myService.send(obj);
```

Your httpService

```
<s:HTTPService id='myService' url='urlToYourPHP' method='POST' result='yourResultHandler' fault='yourFaultHandler' resultFormat='XML'/>
```

As powelljf3 said, POST is more secure then GET though it can still be gotten to.

Comment: Added the following to my edit but figure I should add it here as well;

"Should have read all answers before I posted. Sam DeHaan Beat me to the right answer though I am pretty sure you need obj.paramater vice his obj['paramater']. His method might work as well for all I know. Never tried it."

Comment: Yours should work in most cases. I was concerned about using 'class', as it is a keyword, so I figured I would rather be safe and do it the way I showed.